# Let $(u_n)_{n \in\mathbb{Z}}\in \ell^p(\mathbb{Z)}$ such that $2u_n=u_{n+1}+u_{n-1}$. Then $u_n=0$ for all $n \in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to use $2u_n=u_{n+1}+u_{n-1}$ inductively but this doesn't seem to work. I would just like a hint what do do. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. You might note that $2(1)=1+1$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that $u$ is in $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: $\Delta^2 u=0$ has very simple solutions, and only one very trivial solution in this normed space.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the sequence $v_n=u_{n+1}-u_n$. Then
$$
v_{n+1}=v_n
$$
per initial equation. Now solve backwards.